# How these gifs are made?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-after-effects, adobe-flash

[image]

In which software i can create type of gifs ?

Comment: You tagged three options...

Comment: i was just guessing, pls guide me further

Comment: I haven't got time now but your question is very broad anyway, I'm not sure how exactly they are made is something that can be answered in one Q&A.

Comment: some hints would be enough

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Photoshop Extended .. But it is way easier to do it with Adobe After Effects

Comment: if you know any tutorial about it pls share